# Как сделать аналог groupUniqArray в Vertica?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Есть таблица вида

| user_id | event_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |

Нужно получить на выходе такую

| user_id | events |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [1, 2] |
| 2 | [3, 4, 5] |

В clickhouse я бы использовал такую конструкцию

```
select user_id,
       groupUniqArray(event_id) as events
from db
group by user_id
```

Но в вертике без понятия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, там есть похожая функция listagg(), она вроде groupArray, для уников просто distinct в неё можно передать. Возвращает конечно не массив а строку, но в целом ок

```
select user_id,
   listagg(distinct event_id) as events
from db
group by user_id
```